# How to make an Activity fetch data from the server automatically in android

Tags: android

I am new to Android.I am building an app which will send/retrieve data to/from a server.So what I did is I created a login page and gave credentials for each user.So,once the user logs in,I want the user to be logged in until he signs out.I mean the log in screen should not be visible the next time the user opens the app.So, I have done that using SharedPreferences in android.

```
private EditText mobile,password;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileET);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordET);

String mob = mobile.getText().toString();
String pass = password.getText().toString();

sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(MOBILE,mob);
editor.putString(PASSWORD,pass);
editor.commit();
```

And when the user comes to the next screen,if the user clicks on Back button,the user should not be taken to the Login screen. So, I have used the below code in the next Activity which is the activity that comes after a user is logged in.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

So,this is working fine and when the user clicks on the next Back button,the app is closed and if the user opens the app again,the Second activity is shown.

So,what I want is to for the Second Activity to be loaded with some data from the server whenever the app is opened.The Second Activity should fetch data from the server automatically when the app is opened.Earlier,what I did was I ran a PHP Script to fetch data from the server when the Login button is clicked. But now,since the Login screen will appear only once I am not able to figure out how to fetch the data and reload it with the latest details every time the app is opened.Also there are some validations to be done like the user can input data only once per day.So,when the app is opened,it should also check for that and if the user has already given his/her input for the day,he/she should be redirected to a "Thank You" screen.And if again the user opens the app the next day,it should open the Second Activity where the user can give his input.So how do I do these validations in the Second Activity which comes after the Login Activity. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: try to fetch data inside `onCreate()` or `onResume()` of second activity?

Comment: @Yazan okay,I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Is almost the same idea as you did in the Login Activity. You need to use SharedPreferences too to achieve all of that. And as @Yazan said, you need to do it in those Methods, but I think in onCreate you should do the sinc process (using AsyncTask), and in the onResume you must check if the user already stored the data this day.

Comment: @Jonas452 I will proceed the way you both suggested and come back in case of any issue. thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I would suggest don't use Shared preferences since it's not reliable method of holding data,instead use the App database @Pranami

Comment: @Roy You mean I need to use SQLite or the online Database that I am using i.e MySQL?

Comment: I was talking about SqlLite,Plzz implement ur idea using Sql Lite (u can use Realm),do not use shared preferences because if u clear cache data from settings,U will loose all ur shared preferences data at once.@Pranami

Comment: @Roy okay, I will try implementing as suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call the service on second activity's on create method after setContentView() and fetch the data from the shared preferences and pass that data to the php script and catch response and show the data to the apropreate location.

and the credentials you want to give for one day duration then check the entry with the system date and validate it. if it is belong to the same date then it will pass to the thank you page otherwise it allow user to move to second activity.

Comment: Thanks for the guide.I will try the suggested way and check if it works fine.

Comment: okay if it doesn't work then post your code for batter understand... thank you

Comment: Sure.Thanks for the help :)

Comment: fetch data from the server in the onCreate of the activity using an async task otherwise u would encounter a network on main thread exception

Comment: @Roy yes,I am already using Async Task to fetch data from the server. Thanks for the advice anyway :)

Comment: instead of that u can use the famous and the sweetest Retrofit Library @Pranami

Comment: @Roy okay,I haven't tried using Retrofit Library before but I will surely try to learn about it and implement if it fulfills my needs. :)